A property from the fundamental theorem of galois
I was reading one of James Milne's notes: field and group theory. I came across the fundamental theorem of Galois and one of the properties says :
If H is a subgroup of the Galois group G and M is the corresponding Sub-extension, then the following correspondence is also true :
$\sigma H \sigma^{-1} \leftrightarrow \sigma M$.
The proof says :
Let $\tau \in G$ (the Galois field of E over F) and $\alpha \in E.$ Then $\tau(\alpha)=\alpha$ iff $ \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}(\sigma \alpha) = \sigma \alpha$.
then $\tau$ fixes M iff $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ fixes $\sigma M$, hence $Gal(E/\sigma M) = \sigma Gal(E/M)\sigma^{-1}$.
This is where I am stuck. I did not understand the last line $Gal(E/\sigma M)$ part. $\tau$ is an element of the galois group so how does it fix all elements of M when at first we assumed it only fixes $\alpha$? It's confusing me.

There are two steps.

Fix $\alpha\in M$. If $\tau$ is an element of $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$, then $\tau(\alpha)=\alpha$ if and only if $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}(\sigma\alpha)=\sigma\alpha$.

That means that $\tau(\beta)=\beta$ for all $\beta\in M$ if and only if $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}(\sigma\beta)=\sigma\beta$ for all $\beta\in M$, by applying step 1 to each and every $\beta\in M$. Therefore, $\tau$ fixes $M$ pointwise if and only if $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}$ fixes $\sigma M$ pointwise.


Thus, $\mathrm{Gal}(E/\sigma M) = \sigma\mathrm{Gal}(E/M)\sigma^{-1}$, by point 2.
Note that this isn't about finite fields. It's about any Galois extension.

Ok, I understood why if $\tau$ fixes M. then $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1} $ fixes $\sigma M$. But still not understood the gal correspondence ie... your last line.

@Soumyadeepmandal (Then why did you accept the answer?)  Because by definition $\mathrm{Gal}(E/M)$ is the subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$ of automorphisms that fix $M$ pointwise; and $\mathrm{Gal}(E/\sigma M)$ is the subgroup of automorphisms that fix $\sigma M$ pointwise, and we just said that $\tau\in\mathrm{Gal}(E/M) \iff \sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}\in\mathrm{Gal}(E/\sigma M)$. The last is equivalent to $\tau\in\sigma^{-1}\mathrm{Gal}(E/\sigma M)\sigma$. So you have $\tau\in\mathrm{Gal}(E/M)\iff \tau\in\sigma^{-1}\mathrm{Gal}(E/\sigma M)\sigma$. (cont)

@Soumyadeepmandal So $\mathrm{Gal}(E/M) = \sigma^{-1}\mathrm{Gal}(E/\sigma M)\sigma^{-1}$, which is equivalent to $\sigma\mathrm{Gal}(E/M)\sigma^{-1}=\mathrm{Gal}(E/\sigma M)$.
